# Setting data in viewModel knockoutjs from html5 websocket

Tags: html, knockout.js, websocket, requirejs

I am trying to create knockout.js component that is getting data from HTML5 Websocket. Websocket code is in separate script e.g. util.js. I am able to connect and get data from socket, but dont know how correctly to set corresponding property in component`s ViewModel.

Websocket  - util.js:

```
     var options = {
    server: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '12345'
};

var socket, loadedFlag;
var timeout = 2000;
var clearTimer = -1;
var data = {};

function handleErrors(sError, sURL, iLine)
{
    return true;
};
function getSocketState()
{
    return (socket != null) ? socket.readyState : 0;
}

function onMessage(e)
{
    data=$.parseJSON(e.data);

 // ???? Is it possible to have here something like
 // ???? viewModel.getDataWS1(data);
}

function onError()
{
    clearInterval(clearTimer);
    socket.onclose = function () {
        loadedFlag = false;
    };
    clearTimer = setInterval("connectWebSocket()", timeout);
}

function onClose()
{
    loadedFlag = false;
    clearInterval(clearTimer);
    clearTimer = setInterval("connectWebSocket()", timeout);
}

function onOpen()
{
    clearInterval(clearTimer);
    console.log("open" + getSocketState());
}

function connectWebSocket()
{

    if ("WebSocket" in window)
    {
        if (getSocketState() === 1)
        {
            socket.onopen = onOpen;
            clearInterval(clearTimer);
            console.log(getSocketState());
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                host = "ws://" + options.server + ":" + options.port;
                socket = new WebSocket(host);
                socket.onopen = onOpen;
                socket.onmessage = function (e) {
                    onMessage(e);
                };
                socket.onerror = onError;
                socket.onclose = onClose;
            }
            catch (exeption)
            {
                console.log(exeption);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Component (productDisplay.js) - creating so that is can be used on multiple pages:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'app/models/productDisplayModel',
    'knockout',
    'mapping',
    'socket'
],
        function ($, model, ko, mapping) {
            ko.components.register('product', {
                viewModel: {require: 'app/models/productModel'},
                template: {require: 'text!app/views/product.html'}
            });

        });
```

Product ViewModel (productModel.js) - where I struggle to set viewModel property to data from websocket:

```
var viewModel = {};

define(['knockout', 'mapping', 'jquery'], function (ko, mapping, $) {

    function Product(name, rating) {
        this.name = name;
        this.userRating = ko.observable(rating || null);
    }

    function MyViewModel() {
        this.products = ko.observableArray(); // Start empty
    }

    MyViewModel.prototype.getDataWS1 = function () {

     //Websocket has not connected and returned data yet, so data object is empty
     // ???? Is there anyway I can add something like promise so that the value is set once socket is connected? 
        this.products(data);
    };

// apply binding on page load
    $(document).ready(function () {
        connectToServer1();
        viewModel = new MyViewModel();

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        viewModel.getDataWS1();
    });

});
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Maybe use a callback? Something like connectToServer1(function(data) {this.products(data)}); I can't see where you defined your connectToServer1 so I can't show you how to return callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update an observable when you get a message in the following manner:

**util.js**

```
function onMessage(e) {
    var productData = $.parseJSON(e.data);
    viewModel.addNewProduct(productData);
}
```

**productModel.js**

```
function Product(name, rating) {
    this.name = name;
    this.userRating = ko.observable(rating || null);
}

function MyViewModel() {
    this.products = ko.observableArray(); // Start empty
}

MyViewModel.prototype.addNewProduct(product) {
  var newProduct = new Product(product.name, product.rating);
  this.products.push(newProduct);
}
```

Basically the idea is that when you get a message (in onMessage function), you will parse the data and call a function in your viewmodel to add the message data to the viewmodel properties (observables, observableArrays, etc.)